# How to cast a column to a number while creating a table in SQL server using java?

Tags: sql-server

I want a column in a table to be cast to number while creating a table.Is it possible to do or any way i can achieve this?

```
create table test(name String,age int,currency)
```

I want to cast currency column to number.How can i do this?

Comment: Do you want the `currency` column to store/accept only numeric values. If yes, then use `numeric` datatype.

Comment: provide some code you have tried

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Why not simply create the column as numeric, money, int or whatever data type you need in the first place?

Comment: when creating a new table there is no data so also nothing to cast. Your question makes no sense